# Proof Involving Factors Of Arbitrarily Large Numbers

Tags: proof-writing, factorial, prime-factorization, infinite-product

> For prime $p$, show whether $$\prod_{p \geq 1} p^{\lfloor \frac{x}{p-1} \rfloor} \sim x!$$ as $x$ approaches infinity, and
>   explain.

I don’t know that it’s true, but I thought that it followed, if perhaps somewhat indirectly, from the fact that an arbitrarily large positive integer has, on average, 1 factor of 2, $1/2$ factors of 3, $1/4$ factors of 5, et cetera, so the product of the integers should approach the product of the approximations.

Comment: For clarification, do you mean for the product to be running through all primes less than $x$?

Comment: I think the claim is true, as $\lfloor\frac{x}{p-1}\rfloor$ measures the highest power of $p$ that divides $x$

Comment: @Vedvart1 I dont think less than $x$ is required, as when $p>x$, the term in the exponent is zero, thereby giving us $1$ to multiply with

Comment: The formula for the highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $x!$ is well approximated by $\lfloor x/(p-1)\rfloor$. The sum is approximately geometric!

Comment: From calculating the first few terms of the sequence, you can find it at https://oeis.org/A091137, which references the relationship to the factorial and uses the same argument as vidyarthi. "This is always a relatively small multiple of n!, since the multiplicity with which a prime p divides n! is always <= n/(p-1); it is equal to floor(n/(p-1)) at least when n is a power of p." - Franklin T. Adams-Watters